# How to change the appearance of heading commands in texmaker editor

Tags: texmaker, editors

Is it possible to change the appearance of the different commands in texmaker. So for example below could I have Section commands in a large black font and subsection in a smaller blue font rather than both the same color. This would improve the readibility of long documents in the editor. I have found information for texworks (http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=6921) but I can't find anything for TexMaker

[image]